# In the below code Why doesn't the on event Handler fire up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I not getting a console output,Is there some conceptual mistake
The HTML page is

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>prac 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min (1).js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="just">
<input type="submit" id="submit">

<p></p><p></p>
<div id="div1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also the script2.js is

```
$(document).on('ready',check());

function check(){
  $('#submit').on('click',function(){

    console.log("hi");
  })



}
```

Thanks sdcsc=dsfsdfvdvd(just to eliminate the error of details)

Comment: `submit` without form is meaningless.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yeah but in the end submit is an element so it should fire up on "click"  ??

Comment: Right, it was just a note ..

Comment: `$(document).on('ready'` is deprecated  as per docs http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @charlietfl yeah that was the major problem ...Please write this as an answer and i will Accept it

Comment: Editing the question such that it invalidates existing answers is not okay on Stack Overflow. I'm glad @charlietfl was able to pinpoint the *other* issue with the code.

Comment: $(document).on('ready',check()); // You calling Check() before the page even load. Of course that won't work since #submit doesn't exist yet. Remove the () and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `check()` **calls** `check`, immediately, before the elements exist, and so they aren't found, and the handler isn't hooked up.

You're supposed to pass a *function*, not its return value, into `ready`:

```
$(document).on("ready", check);
// No () --------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to load the JS files at the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

So your HTML file should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>prac 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="just">
<input type="submit" id="submit">

<p></p><p></p>
<div id="div1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min (1).js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```